# Count where multiple columns match a single column in a presence absence matrix

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a presence absence matrix of plant species and it looks something like this...

```
set.seed(123)
Data <- data.frame(
 endemic = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
 val1p1 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
 val1p2 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
 val1p3 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
 val2p1 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
 val2p2 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
 val2p3 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))
Data


   endemic invasive val1p1 val1p2 val1p3 val2p1 val2p2 val2p3
1        1        0      0      1      1      0      0      1
2        1        1      0      0      1      1      0      1
3        1        0      1      0      0      0      1      0
4        0        0      0      1      0      0      1      0
5        0        1      1      0      1      1      1      0
6        1        1      0      0      0      1      0      1
7        1        1      0      0      0      1      1      1
8        1        1      1      1      0      1      0      0
9        0        1      1      1      0      0      1      1
10       0        0      1      0      1      0      1      1
```

The matrix shows if a species (1-10) is endemic or invasive and if it was present (1) in or absent (0) in a plot. The plots are situated in different valleys (val1, val2)

I want to find out how many endemic species are found in valley 1 (val1). Therefore I need to know the combined number of species found in multiple columns (val1p1, val1p2, val1p3) and then how many of those are endemic (i.e. how many of those match with the 'endemic' column).

In this example, the total number of species in valley 1 is 8, of which 4 are endemic. The output I want is just the number of endemic species in valley 1!

My real data set is actually quite large, I have 200 species in 75 plots in 8 different valleys, therefore I need to quick(ish) way to do this!

Obviously I can't sum the the rows, as the same species appear in different plots. I tried using mutate to combine the plots in to separate valleys first...

```
Data %>% mutate(val1 = coalesce(va1p1,val1p2,val1p3)
```

However, this did not work properly as not all 0's were replaced by 1s.

Any suggestions? I am still quite new to R.

Comment: Please update your example data with seed: `set.seed(123);Data <- data.frame( ...` so we can replicate. Also helpful, if you provide expected output.

Answer (score 0):

a first go... double check the !duplicate-part !!!

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame( species = c(1:10),
  endemic = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
  invasive = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
  val1p1 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
  val1p2 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
  val1p3 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
  val2p1 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
  val2p2 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
  val2p3 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))

df

library( tidyverse )

df %>% 
  gather( location, present, matches("^val") ) %>%
  mutate( valley = stringr::str_extract_all( .$location, "\\d", simplify = TRUE )[,1], 
          p      = stringr::str_extract_all( .$location, "\\d", simplify = TRUE )[,2] ) %>%
  filter( valley == 1, present == 1 ) %>%
  #filter out duuplicate species (from the top...) double-check if this is waht you want
  filter( !duplicated( species ) ) 

#   species endemic invasive location present valley p
# 1       1       0        0   val1p1       1      1 1
# 2       4       1        1   val1p1       1      1 1
# 3       6       0        0   val1p1       1      1 1
# 4       7       1        1   val1p1       1      1 1
# 5       8       1        0   val1p1       1      1 1
# 6       5       0        0   val1p2       1      1 2
# 7       9       1        0   val1p2       1      1 2
# 8      10       0        1   val1p3       1      1 3
```